# Is there a way to have conditional data validation based on the contents of another cell in google spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-docs

Examle Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApUbvdjb2dQUdDRIbWVxX25JR29BZHItYXdHZkR2T3c&usp=sharing

I'm wondering if there is a way to to have cell J2 be conditional on the contents of M2, so that only a certain range of numbers (time) can be entered into J2 based on M2? The ranges would be like so: if M2 says "low," then J2 has to be between 1 hour and 200 hours. If it's not a warning comes up or it doesn't allow input (either/or)...

- Low = 1:00:00—200:00:00 (1—200 hours)
- Medium = 200:00:01—300:00:00 (200—300 hours)
- High = 300:00:01—500:00:00 (300—500 hours)

Is this possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Kishan+ via the Google product help forums (http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!mydiscussions/docs/xuji1fC6hd0) the answer can be accomplished via an array formula using a hidden sheet (sloppy, but works); tutorial is here: http://igoogledrive.blogspot.com/2013/07/google-spreadsheet-multi-sub-drop-down.html